# Шаблон Decorator

Tags: java

Всем привет. Интересуют примеры приложений, построенных с поомщью шаблона Decorator.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вообще, "построенных с поомщью шаблона Decorator " - очень уж громко звучит. Использующих ещё можно выразиться.. а то прямо будто свет клином сошёлся на этом паттерне :)

Comment: Да этот шаблон применяют везде, у него другое название есть обертка :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону SWING. На ум пришло ScrollPane и библиотека ввода/вывода.

Answer (score 0):

[декоратор на англ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

[декоратор на ру](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator)

[декоратор в java](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java)